# NSCollectionView UI not updating when I using dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So I have an NSCollectionView that has a list of songs.  When I update that array that the NSCollectionView represents normally the UI reflects that change:

Picture: http://cl.ly/image/1D3A1o192k3W

Code:

```
[self setCurrentPlaylist:[HMRequest playlistPopular3Day]];
```

(Notes: _currentPlaylist is the array, `[HMRequest playlistPopular3Day]` returns an array of songs)

But when I try to use `dispatch_async` all of a sudden the UI goes nuts.  The visible part of the NSCollectionView doesn't update, but when I scroll down, the previously hidden parts update correctly.

Picture (I've scrolled a bit, the blank white is what was previously visible, the songs are the part of the scroll view that was hidden): http://cl.ly/image/3y0f212Y3W3S

Code:

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{        
    [self setCurrentPlaylist:[HMRequest playlistPopular3Day]];
});
```

Any help avoiding that blank UI section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most parts of AppKit aren't threadsafe, so you should only make UI updates on the main thread and not on a background thread. Furthermore, the screenshot looks like you don't actually want to use a `NSCollectionView` but rather a `NSTableView`, which is much much faster in terms of performance.

Comment: Ok, that clears that up. Thanks, real quick what is an example when would you use a `NSCollectionView` instead of an `NSTableView`?

Comment: @AlexMarchant I would never use `NSCollectionView` due to the fact that it creates ALL views at once, even when they aren't visible. But I would use an alternative like (shameless self-plug) `JUCollectionView` when there is a need to display content in multiple columns.

Comment: @AlexMarchant No problem. [Github repo](https://github.com/JustSid/JUCollectionView).